# DataServiceRequestException was unhandled when calling "SaveChanges()" in WCF application

Tags: wcf, exception, wcf-data-services

So i keep getting this error when im trying to save changes in a WCF application

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       MBEMEADataContext cc = new MBEMEADataContext(new Uri("http://ldnmbl-sp10dev/sites/mbemea/_vti_bin/listdata.svc"));
       cc.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

        var source = cc.CaseStudies;
        cc.AddToCaseStudies(
            new CaseStudiesItem
        {
            Title = textBox1.Text,
            Client = textBox2.Text

        });
        cc.SaveChanges();

    }
```

When `cc.SaveChanges();` is called i get "DataServiceRequestException was unhandled" and i dont know why

Comment: did you try to add try-catch to find out exception details?

Comment: Yup and it still just gives me the same error which is "DataServiceRequestExpetion"

Comment: It basically skips the " SaveChange" method

Comment: Change the attribute Client to something else.

Comment: Nope that hasn't worked either.